# Can't concat file paths, permission denied

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I can't realize why if I just try to concat some file paths (without opening the files), I get "permission denied":

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
        path1= "./src/$1"
        path2= "./Main/$1"
        echo $path1
else
        echo "Invalid number of parameters"
fi
```

This is how I execute the bash script (named compare.sh):

[image]

*PS*: `./src/GraphicTest.cpp` and `./Main/GraphicTest.cpp` are existing files.

Comment: Spaces matter! There should not be one after `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables are set using the syntax `name=value`. There must not be any [unquoted] whitespace characters in the declaration.

```
    path1="./src/$1"
    path2="./Main/$1"
    #     ^ remove space here
```

The space in your usage was invoking the other usage of `name=value`, i.e. temporarily setting environment variables for a single program invocation.

For instance:

```
# set environment variable "foo" to "bar" for this invocation of "program"
foo="bar" /path/to/program
# set "baz" to an empty value for the invocation of "program"
baz= /path/to/program
```

The reason you were getting a permission denied error on `path1= "./src/$1"` was because it was taken to mean "Set environment variable path1 to empty and invoke program ./src/$1" and since `./src/$1` doesn't have its executable bit set it failed.